# Is Call/Apply preferable to passing context?

Tags: javascript

I'll just kick it off with a bit of code. Let's have an object:

```
function SomeObject() {
    this.arbitraryVarINeed = 5;
}
```

Now one way would be:

```
SomeObject.prototype.stuffToBeDone() {
    var context = this;
    function heyThere() {
        console.log(context.arbitraryVarINeed);
    }
    heyThere();
}
```

and the other:

```
SomeObject.prototype.stuffToBeDone() {
    function heyThere() {
        console.log(this.arbitraryVarINeed);
    }
    heyThere.call(this);
}
```

Now in this simple example, call would be preferable, obviously. But how about this, is .call/.apply even applicable?

```
SomeObject.prototype.stuffToBeDone() {
    var hello = document.createElement("brofist");
    var context = this;
    hello.onBroEvent = function (event) {
        event.target.innerBro = context.arbitraryVarINeed;
    }
}
```

And if I have to choose between repeatedly using .call/.apply or just saving context saved somewhere, should I go for the former or the latter? What would be the fast option, the safe option, is one of the two approaches just flatout better than the other?

As it turns out thanks to Jakob's answer, the event/anon function example can also be solved via .bind. So is there absolutely no need to pass the context after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full answer to your question, but as for your last example there's a third way to go. Just as you've guessed yourself, you can't really use `call`/`apply`, but you can use `bind`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Like this:

```
SomeObject.prototype.stuffToBeDone() {
    var hello = document.createElement("brofist");
    var context = this;
    hello.onBroEvent = (function(event) {
        event.target.innerBro = this.arbitraryVarINeed;
    }).bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Bind is basically just saving the context in a closure though. IIRC, bind can be polyfilled as something like this (not using prototype for clarity): `function bind(fn, target) { return function() { return fn.call(target, arguments); } }`.

Comment: You have more or less said what I was looking for, even tho the question remains unaswered. I doubt that'll change any time soon, so here you go.